# SQL 3 Type of conditions

Tags: php, sql

I've a proble to generating a results from my sql. Well my sql is for searching data with 3 conditions.

> 1. With transaction number
> 2. By date
> 3. Transcation number and date

Here is my query so far :->

```
select a.totalpembelian,a.idpembelian,notransaksibeli,a.tanggal,c.namabarang,b.totalbarang,c.hargabarang,b.totalharga,d.namasupplier from pembelian_header a 
join pembelian_detail b on 
    a.idpembelian = b.idpembelian left join 
    barang c on b.idbarang = c.idbarang left join supplier d on b.idsupplier=d.idsupplier 
    where (notransaksibeli like '%$notrans%' and a.tanggal='$tanggal')
    or (notransaksibeli like '%$notrans%') or (a.tanggal='$tanggal')
group by totalpembelian
```

I cannot generate the right result if I insert the transaction number and date.

Comment: Are you saying that if transaction number and date match, you don't want to return records where only one of them matches?  Because as is, your criteria are redundant and it will return all records where either match.

Comment: Sory if my english bad. of course i want. Example i have transaction number 002 and the date is 01/02/14 , but when i try to search the transaction number and with the false date, it keep generating result.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, my answer below should be what you're after, you need to add to the last two criteria to require one variable to be empty when matching only on the other variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So logically, your three conditions are actually only 2 conditions.  if you have:

1. A or
2. B or
3. A and B

then #3 will always be true if #1 or #2 are true.  So you can simplify your query a bit there.
But I'm afraid this is only a partial answer because I don't know your actual data or what result you're getting.  However you may find simplifying your query helpful to understanding what it's actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're matching on either, but want to give preference where there's a match on both, you need your criteria to require either both variables be populated, or only one of them be populated, you can do this via `= ''` or `IS NULL` depending on how your unset variables are set up:

```
    where (notransaksibeli like '%$notrans%' and a.tanggal='$tanggal')
    or (notransaksibeli like '%$notrans%' AND $tanggal = '') 
    or (a.tanggal='$tanggal' AND $notrans = '')
group by totalpembelian
```

Or:

```
    where (notransaksibeli like '%$notrans%' and a.tanggal='$tanggal')
    or (notransaksibeli like '%$notrans%' AND $tanggal IS NULL) 
    or (a.tanggal='$tanggal' AND $notrans IS NULL)
group by totalpembelian
```